# Kafka - how to use @KafkaListener(topicPattern="${kafka.topics}") where property kafka.topics is 'sss.*'?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, consumer

I'm trying to implement Kafka consumer with topic names as a pattern. E.g. @KafkaListener(topicPattern="${kafka.topics}") where property kafka.topics is 'sss.*'. Now when I send message to topic 'sss.test' or any other topic name like 'sss.xyz', 'sss.pqr', it's throwing error as below:

WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 12 : {sss.xyz-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

I tried to enable listeners & advertised.listeners in the server.properties file but when I re-start Kafka it consumes messages from all old topics which were tried. The moment I use new topic name, it throws above error.

Kafka doesn't support pattern matching? Or there's some configuration which I'm missing? Please suggest.

Comment: Kafka does support pattern matching see [kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.regex.Pattern-), You are using `@KafkaListener` which is from spring-Kafka project, which also supports pattern see [spring Kafka docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#topicPattern--)

Comment: Yes, I implemented it looking at these documents. But when I try to send message to topic, it's throwing LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE. That's the main issue.

Comment: I think the problem that Kafka doesn’t support dynamic topics. In other words if you add topic at run time, it isn’t picked up by the current consumer. You should restart consumer to subscribe to new topics

Comment: Try using regular expressions, for me topicPattern = "[\\s\\S]+" is the regexp for every topic, i think you can work from there